# TSQL get the previous and any proceeding records based on recordset provided

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    fs.FILOID currentfilo,
    ISNULL(LEAD(af.FILOID) OVER (ORDER BY StartTransactionTimeUTC), fs.Next_FILOID) Nextfilo,
    ISNULL(LAG(af.FILOID) OVER (ORDER BY StartTransactionTimeUTC), fs.Previous_FILOID) lf 
FROM 
    [DataWarehouseCore].[DWC_FILOSummary] fs 
JOIN 
    [AttendanceCore].[AC_FILO] af ON af.FILOID = fs.FILOID
WHERE 
    fs.Employee_ID = 15049
    AND Client_ID = 306
```

Which returns the following results:

```
currentfilo Nextfilo    lf
----------------------------
5           2           NULL
2           3           5
3           6           2
6           7           3
7           1           6
1           NULL        7
```

I only want to have to see currentfilo 3, 6, 7 , 1 if ID 6 was passed in. So instead of returning what I have in my result set just the previous and next records which are actually based on a date field.

Here is some examples of data and what I expect to see this is the parent table: AC_FILO

```
FILOID  ClientID    EmployeeID  StartTransactionTimeUTC
-----------------------------------------------------------
5       306         15049       2021-08-29 02:53:00.0000000
2       306         15049       2021-09-01 06:46:00.0000000
3       306         15049       2021-09-02 07:50:00.0000000
6       306         15049       2021-09-06 08:56:00.0000000
7       306         15049       2021-09-10 07:58:00.0000000
1       306         15049       2021-09-15 07:45:00.0000000
```

What I want in my new table is an ordered list of the current FILOID, the next FILOID and previous FILOID is based on the StartTransactionTimeUTC

For example when FILOID 6 was inserted I would want to see the previous FILOID to FILOID 6 followed by all proceeding FILOID's based on the date!

For example I would want to see

```
CurrentFilo NextFilo LastFilo
-----------------------------
3           6        2
6           7        3
7           1        6
1           NULL     7
```

Comment: You would need to use a subquery and `STRING_AGG` to achieve this, and this query is unlikely to be performant due to the triangular join.

Comment: `in the order they are in this table` data have no orders inside in the table and database engine will return not sorted data if `order by` is not provided, so your method is not gonna work

Comment: In this data and this result set, what is "ID" when you say "ID = 6". I'm not understanding your data enough to guide here. I'm assuming `FILOID` but that is present in both tables and is present in all three columns in your result set. Is this a parent/child relationship in this data? If so a recursive CTE would solve your problems.

Answer (score 2):

It's not totally clear what you're after, but given the final desired results and input value of `6`, I take it to mean you want the `(CurrentFilo, NextFilo,LastFilo)` sets ordered by `StartTransactionTimeUTC` starting with the point where a given `NextFilo` occurs, since the `6` input matches the `6` in that place in the expected result.

---

As a first step, start with not caring about anything passed in and only create the next/last result for the entire table. We can use the [`LAG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`LEAD()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) window functions to do this.

You've done most of this work already in the question's first code listing, but let's also include the `StartTransactionTimeUTC` field for now, so we will be able to reproduce the correct order in later steps. I'm also using a simplified schema right now so I can reproduce this on SQL Fiddle:

```
SELECT  FILOID as CurrentFILO,
    LEAD(FILOID) OVER (ORDER BY StartTransactionTimeUTC) as NextFILO,
    LAG(FILOID) OVER (ORDER BY StartTransactionTimeUTC) as LastFILO,
    StartTransactionTimeUTC
FROM AC_FILO
```

Now for a given `NextFILO` value like `6` we can find the desired `StartTransactionTimeUTC` time of that record by using a Common Table Expression (CTE), like this:

```sql
WITH FILOTree AS (
    SELECT  FILOID as CurrentFILO,
        LEAD(FILOID) OVER (ORDER BY StartTransactionTimeUTC) as NextFILO,
        LAG(FILOID) OVER (ORDER BY StartTransactionTimeUTC) as LastFILO,
        StartTransactionTimeUTC
    FROM AC_FILO
)
SELECT StartTransactionTimeUTC
FROM FILOTree
WHERE NextFILO = 6
```

We could also use a nested inner SELECT instead of the CTE. The important thing is we need a layer of indirection around the initial query in order to use a `WHERE` clause with a window function like `LAG()` or `LEAD()`. But I prefer the CTE in this case for reasons that will become clear later.

Once we know the correct `StartTransactionTimeUTC` we can get the final results using the same technique:

```sql
WITH FILOTree AS (
    SELECT  FILOID as CurrentFILO,
        LEAD(FILOID) OVER (ORDER BY StartTransactionTimeUTC) as NextFILO,
        LAG(FILOID) OVER (ORDER BY StartTransactionTimeUTC) as LastFILO,
        StartTransactionTimeUTC
    FROM AC_FILO
)
SELECT CurrentFILO, NextFILO, LastFILO
FROM FILOTree
WHERE StartTransactionTimeUTC >= '2021-09-02 07:50:00'
ORDER BY StartTransactionTimeUTC
```

This produces the correct results, but from the wrong input. However, now we can use the same CTE (aha!) to put the two pieces together into the same query without repeating code for the initial current/next/last projection, like this:

```
WITH FILOTree As (
   SELECT  FILOID as CurrentFILO,
       LEAD(FILOID) OVER (ORDER BY StartTransactionTimeUTC) as NextFILO,
       LAG(FILOID) OVER (ORDER BY StartTransactionTimeUTC) as LastFILO,
       StartTransactionTimeUTC
   FROM AC_FILO
)
SELECT CurrentFILO, NextFILO, LastFILO
FROM FILOTree 
WHERE StartTransactionTimeUTC >= (
   SELECT StartTransactionTimeUTC 
   FROM FILOTree
   WHERE NextFILO = 6
)
ORDER BY StartTransactionTimeUTC
```

See it work here:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/24979/2

---

Finally, as I said before, these examples use a simplified schema from the actual production system. So let's plug the original query into the CTE:

```
WITH FILOTree As (
    SELECT fs.FILOID currentfilo 
        , ISNULL(LEAD(af.FILOID) over (order by StartTransactionTimeUTC), fs.Next_FILOID) Nextfilo
        , ISNULL(LAG(af.FILOID) over (order by StartTransactionTimeUTC), fs.Previous_FILOID) LastFILO
        , StartTransactionTimeUTC
    FROM [DataWarehouseCore].[DWC_FILOSummary] fs 
    JOIN [AttendanceCore].[AC_FILO] af ON af.FILOID = fs.FILOID
    WHERE fs.Employee_ID = 15049
        AND Client_ID = 306
)
SELECT CurrentFILO, NextFILO, LastFILO
FROM FILOTree 
WHERE StartTransactionTimeUTC >= (
    SELECT StartTransactionTimeUTC 
    FROM FILOTree
    WHERE NextFILO = 6
)
ORDER BY StartTransactionTimeUTC
```

The only things I had to change from that initial SQL command were adding `StartTransactionTimeUTC` to the `SELECT` list and the alias name for the `LastFILO` column.

Note this *will* run the CTE twice and it will *not* cache any results between the two runs, so be aware of that as a performance concern.

Comment: This is exactly what I am after I think, thank you so much!